# SharedPreferences : Why are they called so?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

As per my understanding the values stored using the SharedPreferences in android can be used only by the app which created it.(correct me if wrong).

Then what is the significance of the name **Shared**Preferences.

Is something really shared here?

Answer (score 4):

well it can be shared accross applications if you set the mode to WORLD READABLE or WORLD_WRITEABLE. (think ringtone settings, notification message etc...)

see this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

```
public static final int MODE_WORLD_READABLE
Since: API Level 1

File creation mode: allow all other applications to have read access to 
the created file.
```

Comment: Thats intresting. So u mean to say we can have a common sharedPrefrence File made as WORLD_WRITABLE and can be accessed across apps? But is it a standard practice?

Comment: Yes they can be. the ringtone preference as i said for example is stored in shared preferences and can be accessed and changed from any app. And i don't think its a common practice. in general you reveal your info to other apps when you want them to be able to read your settings, configuration, get your data. that isn't always a bad thing. Imagine creating a gallery. you want other apps to be able to connect to it. its the same with the content provider as it's with shared preferences. it depends on the situation and the type of app you are building.

Answer (score 1):

The SharedPreferences use a secure /data directory for preferences that are shared within your app's activities and services.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: Is it just that prefrences are Shared within the app's activities and services so this name?